# Selecting elements from Python array

Tags: python, csv

I have used the code below to grab data from a CSV file and putting it into a list. The output is a series of lists, within lists, an array.

I want to grab the first item form each row in the CSV file and assign it to a variable. The code I developed works but is very long winded. I'm interested in modifying the second part of the code if possible not the loop.

```
with open('player1.csv', 'rb') as f: 

    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    your_list = list(reader)     

print "First Player"
Player1 = your_list[0:1]
Player1name = (Player1[0:1])
Player1name = (Player1name[0])
Player1name = (Player1name[0])
print Player1name
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is you want? You want a loop instead of repeating the latter part of that code over and over? Also why repeat the line Player1name = (Player1name[0])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about putting the first item of each item of each row into an array instead of having a separate variable for each item?

So something like this using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
player_names = [row[0] for row in your_list]
```

And if you want to print them:

```
for name in player_names:
    print name
```

Answer (score 0):

By the description provided, it is assumed that you would like to evaluate an instruction stored in a `string` *i.e.,* Taken from: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/

```
>>> code = compile('a = 1 + 2', '<string>', 'exec')
>>> exec code
>>> print a
3
```

However, this is a heavy procedure to execute each time you lookup each CSV fle. Why you would not use a Dictionary and add each variable with key `playerNname`. e.g., `playerDict = {'player1Name':var1, 'player2Name':var2, ..., 'playerNName':varN}`?